# Method to convert binary number to decimal

Tags: groovy, binary

I tried to write a program that converts a binary number to a decimal but am getting a number of errors and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

```
// Takes exponent from the user and calculates 2 ** exponent
int power2(int exponent) {
    result = 2 ** exponent
    return result
}

// Converts binary number to decimal
int binary2decimal(String binary) {
    result = 0
    count = 0
    for (i = binary.length(); i-- > 0;) {
        int d = Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i))
            if (d == 1) {
                result = result + power2(count)
            }
            count ++
    }
    return result
}

binary2decimal("101110")
```

Comment: are you looking to develop the algorithm as a challenge or do you want to use available methods?

Comment: It isto develop the algorithm as a challenge. It is assumed that we have no knowledge of available methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int d = Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(i))
```

to

```
int d = Integer.parseInt("${binary[i]}")
```

and it will work.

An alternative implementation to yours is:

```
int binary2decimal2(String binary) {
    binary.reverse()
          .toList()
          .indexed()
          .collect { Integer idx, String val -> Integer.parseInt(val) * (2 ** idx)}.sum()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the first solution to change my algorithm. However could you please explain exactly the method "${binary[i]}") (I assume it takes the value of the position at i). But why can a character not be parsed as an Integer using the.charAt method?

Comment: `charAt` returns a `char`...  `parseInt` takes a `String`... `"${binary[i]}"` is a String

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the shortest route to a clean solution, use:

`Integer.parseInt(String base2num, int radix)`, where `radix = 2`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Thank you but for the purpose of this exercise it is assumed that we do not  know/ can not use these kinds of methods and have to build an algorithm similar to the one I have posted.